# Api is rejecting params sent from Volley POST method when i put ssl to my domain

Tags: php, android, post, https, android-volley

my domain is now using ssl before that the api's where working perfectly fine on http, as now it got the https the api's are not receiving my volley POST params . I tried

1. HttpsTrustManager
2. NukeSSLCerts

but nothing happened so, I have few questions 
1. putting api's on Https is bad idea
2. Something is missing in my API for POST

```
<?php
require_once("../config/functions.inc.php");
require_once("../classes/regis.php");
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$data = array(); 
if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) and $_REQUEST['id']!=''))
{
$error = '';
$id = trim($_REQUEST'id']);
$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
$pass = trim($_REQUEST['pass']);
}
else
{
deliverResponse(200,'Wrong attempt',NULL);
}

function deliverResponse($status,$status_msg,$data=''){
    $response['status'] = $status;
    $response['status_msg'] = $status_msg;
    $response['data'] = $data;

    $json_response = json_encode($response);
enter code here    echo $json_response;
}
?>
```

I searched Https for Volley and I found this [link](https://github.com/moltak/android-https-volley)

plus I got one more link [this](https://mc-programming.blogspot.in/2014/10/android-volley-https-with-self-signed.html) for Android Volley https with self-signed certificate

Comment: Add the Android Code!

Comment: remove android tag

Comment: Try using `$id = trim($_REQUEST['id']);` and Make sure that you are sending the params key as **id**

Comment: Here you forget to add single quote before `id` , so put that . `$id = trim($_REQUEST['_id']);` Hope this Helps.